# CSV file source is SFTP and in UTF-16. How to save it in UTF_8 form in ADF or ADB

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

The data in file is coming in UTF-16 and need to save it in UTF-8 how to handle it using ADF and ADB?

[image]

Comment: [Handling data encoding issues while ...](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/handling-data-encoding-issues-while-loading-data-to-sql-data-warehouse/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Copy Data" activity in **AZURE DATA FACTORY** and follow to these instructions to convert a UTF-16 encoded file from an SFTP server to UTF-8 in Azure Data Factory.

- Select the SFTP dataset that corresponds to the folder containing the UTF-16 encoded file in the Source section.
- Select the encoding property to "UTF-16" in the Source section of the "Settings" tab.
- Choose the file dataset that corresponds to the location where the UTF-8 file will be stored in the Sink section.
- Set the encoding property to "UTF-8" under the "Settings" tab in the Sink section.

[image]

The "Copy Data" activity will read the UTF-16 file from the SFTP server, convert it to UTF-8, and write it to the target when the pipeline is activated.

Comment: It is not working for me